# <p:remoteCommand > is not invoked when application accessed from other machines

Tags: javascript, java, primefaces, jsf-2.2

This is my scenario,

I have page "myPage.xhtml" where I have added a **java script** to catch the browser/tab close event. which intern perform a **logout** method call using 
**remoteCommand**.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3c.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    xmlns:pm="http://primefaces.org/mobile"
    xmlns:fn="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions">
<f:view >
    <h:head>
        <meta name="metaport"
            content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
            <h:outputStylesheet library="mylib" name="css/queries.css" />
            <script lang="JavaScript">
                window.onbeforeunload = confirmExit;
                function confirmExit() 
                {
                    warnUser();
                }
            </script>
        <f:view renderKitId="MOBILE_KIT" />
    </h:head>
    <h:body id="body">
        <pm:page id="myPage">
            <pm:header title="" styleClass="header">
                <h:graphicImage library="img" name="images/logo.png"
                    styleClass="logo" />
                <h:outputLink id="menu-bar" styleClass="menu_float">
                    <span id="menu_float" class="menu-icon"> <span></span>
                    </span>
                </h:outputLink>
            </pm:header>
            <pm:content styleClass="content">
                <h:form prependId="false">
                    <p:remoteCommand name="warnUser" actionListener="#{myModel.logout()}" />
                </h:form>

                </pm:content>
            </pm:page>
    </h:body>
</f:view>
</html>
```

I started the web page in the **eclipse** and accessed using url's localhost:8081/myapp or http://176.124.xxx.xxx:8082/myapp from the same machine the method call is invoked on browser / tab close event and logout is done.

But if I try to access the url http://176.124.xxx.xxx:8082/myapp from other machine and try the same scenario, the logout method is not triggered.

Is there anything I missed out, I am bit confused. why its not working ?

**update:**

I found the issue . I have modified the script to identify whether the event is actually fired, by holding the page from instant close.

```
 <script lang="JavaScript">
        window.onbeforeunload = confirmExit;
        function confirmExit() 
        {
            warnUser();
            return "do you want to close";
        }
    </script>
```

On this condition I found that the logout method is called after few seconds. because the page is not closed instantly due to the user confirmation pop up in script holds the page from closing.

Is there any other way to overcome this issue ?

Comment: Most browsers have developer tools with an error console. Usually you access if by pressing F12. Is there perhaps some kind of security error reported by the browser?

Comment: @Gimby Thansk for your suggestion, i have updated my question with the issue found.